# Correctly use variable in awk script

Tags: variables, awk

I have a file with many lines, like this:

```
 one     3456    orange
 two     6690    grape
 three   5570    apple
 four    6683    pear
 five    8847    cherry
 six     9035    banana
```

So I write a awk script to catch this output:

```
apple banana cherry
```

It looks like this:

```
awk '/three/ { a = $3}; /six/ { b = $3}; /five/ { c = $3} END {print  a" " b" "c}' <file
```

But this doesn't look the best way becuase I keep using `$3` - how do I catch this variable to reuse it?

Comment: It would help us to come up with a better solution, if you'd tell us why (on what criteria are you picking those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing particularly wrong with doing it the way you are. If you use a variable, it will have to be repeated. However, you could use an array to accumulate your values.

Here is an example of using a simple variable:

```
awk '{var = $3} /three/ {a = var}; /six/ {b = var}; /five/ {c = var} END {print a, b, c}' file
```

Here is an example using an array:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^(three|six|five)$/ {arr[++c] = $3} END {for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {printf "%s%s", delim, arr[i]; delim = OFS}; printf "\n"}' file
```

You don't need to use redirection. AWK can accept filenames as arguments.

In a `print` statement, commas substitute the value of `OFS` (by default a space) so you don't need to use `" "`.

In the array version, you can easily change the regex since it's all in one place.

Comment: Thank you. Also, the advise about the array is very helpful: I will have to study some more awk :)

Comment: Sorry: the array only prints `banana banana banana`

Comment: @Edouard: Sorry, the `c` should be `i` as in `arr[i]` in the `END` block. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thank you for the correction. One problem remains: array now prints `apple cherry banana` - is it possible using array to print in the correct order?

Comment: @Edouard: It's printing in the order that they appear in the file. What do you consider the proper order?

Comment: my original solution (and your first answer) prints them in the correct order `apple banana cherry` Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Edouard: So sorted? Or not sorted but in the order that the fields are listed (as in the first version)? Note carefully that these choices are very different and may only coincidentally have the same output (in this case).

Comment: I was trying to print them in the order: `apple banana cherry` as in your first answer (the non-array one). If this is not possible with the array, I;m happy with the first version. Thanks you.

Comment: @Edouard: The array version can print in that specific order in at least two different ways. The ways that I asked about in my previous comment. Either one adds complexity. I can't help but think that the real problem you're trying to solve is quite different than the representation in your question and could benefit from the kind of generalization that my array version could provide. It your problem is as simple as the one in your question then it's hardly worth scripting at all and the original version you supplied is more than adequate. I'm happy to help, but I'm wondering if I am.

Comment: yes - you have helped alot: thank you. I think you are right about the added complexity of the array not being worth the effort. My problem is a simple one and your first version answer is very nice. Many thanks.